# intersect a subvariety with a Schubert variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, schubert-calculus

Let $Y$ be an irreducible subvariety inside $Gr(r,n)$ (Grassmannian of $r$-plane inside $\mathbb{C}^n$) and $X_\lambda$ be a Schubert variety corresponding to $\lambda$. Assume that $codim(Y)+codim(X_\lambda)=dim(Gr(r,n))$ and let $[Y]\cup [X_\lambda]=d[point] \in H^*(Gr(r,n))$.

I know in general there is an open dense set $O\subset GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that the intersection between $g\cdot Y$ and $X_\lambda$ is generically transverse for all $g \in O$ so number of points in $g\cdot Y\cap X_\lambda$ is $d$.

Suppose now we know that $Y\cap X_\lambda$ is zero dimensional so it is just a union of points. (the intersection may not be transverse) Let say there are $e$ points (counted with multiplicity). Can we have any relation between $d$ and $e$? Do we have $e\le d$?

I apologize if this question is not suitable for this site.

Comment: We have $e=d$, and indeed the question would be more appropriate on MSE. This goes back (at least) to Serre, *Algèbre locale et multiplicités.*